# Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 - ‘Night Light’ flickers occasionally

Tags: display, colors, budgie

Essentially, I have Night Light enabled in the panel to change my colour temperature

Occasionally (every few minutes) I get a brief flicker or two where the temperature switches back to what it was when Night Light was off, and then back again.

Why is this conflict happening?
What could be fighting in the display settings that I have overlooked?

Many thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue haven't been able to find what causes this either

Answer (score 8):

I've had that same problem and was able to find the source of the problem.

I had another program installed before 18.04 called "Red Shift" that was conflicting with the "Night light" feature. I removed that program and the issue was fixed since then.

You should check if you do not have another program that tries to manage the screen at the same time.

Comment: Ah. I don't have redshift installed. That's not my solution, sadly ^^;

Comment: @Nectar maybe you have flux/xflux installed, which does the same.

Comment: I have the same problem, uninstalled Redshift and rebooted and the problem remains. I'm running the proprietary NVidia video card driver.

Comment: `sudo apt remove redshift`

Comment: even after a `sudo apt remove redshift` the process remained somehow. I had to `pkill redshift` after finding it with `ps -A | grep red*`. After killing the process I had to go to the gnome display settings and toggle night light OFF/ON to get it working normally again. Phew! I had been pushing off this error for years and finally my eyes can rest easy! I'm sure a reboot would do the same though.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was flux that I was running , along with Night Light in GNOME.

I removed the conflicting service, and didnt even need to reboot - Night Light started working as expected again.